# Replace zero with last valid value Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm using mysql to store Kwh usage of my home. I get a fault rarely and get a 0 value to get stored. When i extract the values from my table i don't want to get that 0s but the last valid value before.

```
SELECT unix_timestamp(dataora) as time, kwhg 
FROM misure 
WHERE dataora BETWEEN '2013-10-08 00:00:00.000' AND '$data_scelta 23:59:59.997' 
GROUP BY date(dataora),hour(dataora)
```

I used the above code to get the below table:

```
+-------+-----------+
| time  | kwhg      | 
+-------+-----------+
|   9   |    2      |
|   10  |    3      |
|   11  |    0      |
|   12  |    4      |
|   13  |    0      |
+-------+-----------+`
```

I want to obtain

```
+--------+----------+
| time  | kwhg      | 
+-------+-----------+
|   9   |    2      |
|   10  |    3      |
|   11  |    3      |
|   12  |    4      |
|   13  |    4      |
+-------+-----------+`
```

and remove the zero with the previus value.
Any tricks to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL user-defined variables to return either the current row's value of `kwhg` if it's greater than zero, or else the variable defined on the previous row.

```
SELECT unix_timestamp(dataora) as time, @kwhg := IF(kwhg>0, kwhg, @kwhg) AS kwhg 
FROM misure 
WHERE dataora BETWEEN '2013-10-08 00:00:00.000' AND '$data_scelta 23:59:59.997' 
GROUP BY date(dataora),hour(dataora)
```

Like @OddEssay's answer, this can't come up with a nonzero value if the first entry is zero. In that case, it will return whatever the current value of `@kwhg` is, which is probably NULL unless you've run the query before in the current session.

Comment: Great! Thanks! To avoid NULL i've runned a query with set @kwhg=0 and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If it's a small result set, you could simply loop over it and created a fixed dataset with something like:

```
$fixedResults = array();
$lastGoodReading = 0;
foreach($results as $row){
    if($row['kwhg']){
        $fixedResults[$row['time']] = $row['kwhg'];
        $lastGoodReading = $row['kwhg'];
    } else {
        $fixedResults[$row['time']] = $lastGoodReading;
    }
}
```

Which will work if there is multiple failed readings in a row, but will still give zero if the first result fails.

You might also want to do something a bit more advanced, like checking both the previous result, and the next result and take an average of the two.

Answer (score 0):

in mysql

```
  UPDATE mytable
    SET kwhg = (@n := COALESCE(number, @n))
    ORDER BY time;



 @n is a MySQL user variable
```

Comment: COALESCE() only works to substitute for NULL, but zero (0) is not NULL.